# Javascript:Toggle Function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, slidetoggle, togglebutton

I am trying to make a simple toggle but it is not working.And i want it done in javascript not in jquery.
Here is my javascript.

```
<script>
function showhide() {

    if (document.getElementById(ptag).style.display = "block") {
        document.getElementById(ptag).style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(ptag).style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<input type="button" value="Show hide" onclick="showhide()">
<p id="ptag">Some text here.</p>
```

I need solution :(

Comment: did you try `getElementById('ptag')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `if` condition to:

```
if(document.getElementById("ptag").style.display == "block"){
                           ^^^^ string                ^^^ double equals
```

And replace all other references of `ptag` to `"ptag"`

[See working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/qQxnU/)

Comment: Sorry? Your question wasn't really upvote worthy to be honest. I'm not sure you tried to find the solution yourself in anyway before asking here.